# Hexbin plot with calculated colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"x" : [2,4,5,8,5,4,1,6,8,7],
    "y" : [2,4,1,3,7,8,9,3,6,9],
    "z" : ["A","B","B","A","B","A","A","B","B","A"]})
```

The columns `"x"` and `"y"` contain x and y coordinates, while the column `"z"` contains associated labels. Now I would like to create [`plt.hexbin`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin) plot using the `'jet'` colourmap. The values of the bins and thus the colors should not be given by the density of points but should reflect the fraction of points labeled "B" in the bin ((count "B")/(count "B"+count"A")).

Any idea how I can achieve this ?

Comment: Uh, is this `R` or `Python`?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Just corrected !

Comment: wow thanks ! early morning post...

Comment: For me, a hexbin plot  is about _counting_ the number of samples in each of  many hexagonal tiles that tesselate a 2D plane but  your problem description, albeit vague, doesn't specify a collection of 2D points...

Comment: @gboffi my 2D points are x and y.

Comment: Thanks to [jotasi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6614295/jotasi)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42574789/2749397) I have eventually understood your question.  Note that jotasi states that they had to do a bit of guess-work to answer your Q... You might formulate your questions more clearly. (ps, downvote isn't mine...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, you can use the `C` parameter which represents the value of each point. These values will be reduced by the function given by `reduce_C_function` which defaults to `np.mean`. (This is also documented in the [api](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin).) The value you want for each bin is exactly the mean of all values when you assign 1 to every "B" and 0 to every "A". So this will give you the desired result:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [2,4,5,8,5,4,1,6,8,7],
                   "y" : [2,4,1,3,7,8,9,3,6,9],
                   "z" : ["A","B","B","A","B","A","A","B","B","A"]})

plt.hexbin(df["x"], df["y"], C=df["z"]=="B", gridsize=4, cmap=plt.get_cmap("jet"))
plt.scatter(df["x"], df["y"], c=df["z"]=="B", cmap=plt.get_cmap("viridis"))
plt.show()
```

Here the scatter plot is only there to verify that the binning is correct. The coloring is yellow for "B" and violet for "A".
The result looks like:
[image]

Reducing the `gridsize=2` shows that this works also for more than one point per bin:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @jotasi, this is brilliant! And sorry if you had to guess to answer my question.